# SQL запрос на количество одинаковых записей

Tags: group-by

Всем добрый день!
Подскажите возможно ли сделать SQL запрос чтобы получить количество одинаковых userIp при этом не группируя их, т. к. нужны userEmail

| userIp | userID | userEmail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 198.23.0.1 | 1111 | user1@mail.ru |
| 198.23.0.1 | 2222 | user2@mail.ru |
| 199.23.0.1 | 3333 | user3@mail.ru |

Comment: Покажите требуемый ответ для показанных данных. Ну и скажите точную версию СУБД.

Comment: select count(userEmail), group_concat(userEmail)  from yourTable group by userIp

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно! работает)